# How can I use the $subscriptions variable outside of the my-subscriptions.php template?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscriptions, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using Woocommerce Subscription extension, and I would like to display the current subscription orders located in the my-subscriptions.php template on the orders.php template (normal woocommerce template).

When I copy the code over, I get the message of "Undefined variable: subscriptions".

How do I get round this?

EDIT: My files are as follows :

```
Orders.php - https://pastebin.com/0fxgAjyp
my-subscriptions.php - https://pastebin.com/XhbWEBSp
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are accessing the variable inside the function. Please try with `global`

**my-subscriptions.php**

```
function custom_func(){
  global $subscriptions;
}
```

**orders.php**

```
include `my-subscriptions.php`;
 global $subscriptions;
echo   $subscriptions;
```

Comment: thank you for this - i have tried but did not work, i have put links to my two files in pastebin in the original post. there will be some code there that is irrelevant

Comment: For anyone interested I got round this with the following:

`$mainContent = jQuery('#load-subscription');
 $mainContent.load('<?php echo site_url();?>/my-account/subscriptions/ #mycurrentsubscription > *', function() {
...code here to do stuff
}`